# Template a List getter function properly

Tags: java, list

I'm trying to create a getter function with templating for a `List` in Java.  This was my attempt at it but I am not sure I syntax'd it properly even though intellij is ok with it.  Can someone verify this is how to template the function properly?

```
public static <T> List getList(String path)
{
    return getList(path, null);
}

public static <T> List getList(String path, List<T> def)
{
    if (!initialized) {
        init();
    }

    return config.getList(path, def);
}
```

The signature for `config.getList()` can be found here: http://jd.bukkit.org/rb/apidocs/org/bukkit/configuration/MemorySection.html

Thanks

Comment: In Java, we call them generic methods and generic types. Your return type is not parameterized. You probably want it to be.

Comment: I want it to be able to return any type of list.  I'm not sure what you mean by parameterized.  Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: A class/method can have generic type parameters. A `List` can either be raw (no type parameters in declaration) or parameterized, ie. type parameter. For example, `List<T>` or `List<Integer>` or `List<Whatever>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want `public static <T> List<T> getList...`.  You *may* always want to put T in the formal parameters of the class that this code is in, rather than allow it to be different for every call, but that depends on context.